# Refresh categories and mail headers in Outlook

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, email-headers

Through EWS I set a category for the email and I modify the header. The category and the changed header appears in Outlook after a few minutes and sometimes you need to restart Outlook to refresh the e-mail box. How can I force a refresh for the categories and headings in Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

No. Outlook caches the data displayed in the preview pane - it only sees changes made through the UI or the Outlook Object Model on the same machine.

Changes displayed in the Explorer view (message list) will be displayed immediately as soon as the data is synchronized with the server.